# Nested Javascript Conditional

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find why this isn't working for me. 
I want a conditional statement to change a fileformat based on a checked radio button. I've managed to get it to work for a data type, but not the file extension.
Please can someone tell me why this isn't working?
Thanks

```
function GetType() {
        var type = '';
        var fle = '.xml';
        var datatype = document.getElementsByName('dtype');

        for (var i =0; i < datatype.length; i++) {

        if (datatype[i].checked){
            type = datatype[i].value; 
            alert('datatype value is ' + datatype[i].value);
            alert('type is ' + type);
            if (type = 'csv'){
                fle = '.csv';
                alert(fle)}
            else {
                fle = '.xml';
                alert(fle);
            }   
            break;
         }
}
```

Each radio button has a value and one of them has "csv". So I want the fileformat to be .xml unless this particular button has been clicked. 
Then the link is

```
window.parent.location.href='/tracks/<?php echo $_GET["full_filename"]; ?>' + fle + '?xml_type=' + type;?>'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `type = 'csv'` is an assignment not a comparison. This should be `type === 'csv'`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change:

```
if (type = 'csv'){
```

to:

```
if (type == 'csv'){
```

---

In javascript, `=` is assignment, not comparison.

`==` is for comparison with type-conversion allowed.

`===` is for comparison without type-conversion allowed and should generally be your default choice for equality comparison.

Comment: @actionjack - see my extra note about using `===`.